# Monitor Serve side json file for changes, angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn Angular 2 by building a simple app that monitors a JSON file on the server for changes and updates the view with any changes.

I have set up a service which returns an observable to update the view - I think I understand that part of Angular. What I haven't understood is how to monitor the JSON file sitting on the server for changes. That is, when a new record is added to the file, what is the best way to retrieve that new record with Angular?

Is this a matter of retrieving the file again and repopulating the model. Or is there a "more correct" way of doing this?

Many thanks

JT

Answer (score 0):

You need a backend that notifies your front end of the changes. You can't do this entirely in Angular.

Comment: Do you know which libraries would be best for this?

Comment: Totally depends on what language you are writing your backend in.

Comment: I've tried to be a bit more specific in my question. Sorry, it was a bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. Using an IntervalObservable I was able to pole the server ever 3 seconds. The observable would then update my model which would be reflected in the view.

```
   import {IntervalObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';

   ...

    private serverRequest() {
        return IntervalObservable.create(3000)
            .flatMap(() => this.http.get('/file.json'))
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch((error) => {/* error handling */});
    }
```

If you've got a better way of doing this please let me know.

Cheers

JT

Comment: polling server every 3 seconds, getting file and doing model changes seems bit costly to me. How about checking modified time in server, if any changes are done in server by comparing time between front end and backend send the file else return false